# how to remove selectize.js "add..." menu when an item is being typed

Tags: selectize.js

how to remove selectize.js "add..." menu when an item is being typed?
This image facilitates the meaning:

[image]

Answer (score 14):

Set `create: false` in the [Selectize options](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md).  This will limit the user to choosing from the existing options, disallowing adding new ones.

Comment: Yeah, I strongly support @qwertzman opinion. It should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I use create: false (which is the default as per the documentation) and the "add" option pops up nonetheless.